# Receiving error code during output redirection using execvp

Tags: c, exec, fopen, io-redirection, dup2

I am trying to redirect the output from `ls` to a file, in a shell I created in C. I type in:

```
ls > junk
```

and what I get out is:

```
ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory
```

Then if I use CTRL-D to exit the shell it prints the results of the ls command to the screen before exiting. I tried to use print statements to figure out where it is happening and no print statements get printed after:

```
dup2(f, STDOUT_FILENO); Also tried  dup2(f, 1);
```

Code:

```
            pid = fork();

            if(pid == 0)
            {
              // Get the arguments for execvp into a null terminated array  
                    for(i = 0; i <= count; i++)
                    {   if(i == count)
                        {
                            args[i] = (char *)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
                            args[i] = '\0';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            str = strlen(string[i]);
                            args[i] = malloc(str);
                            strcpy(args[i], string[i]);                     
                        }
                    }                       

                if(count == 1)
                {

                }
                else if(strcmp(string[(numargs + 1)], ">") == 0) //numargs is the number of arguments typed in by the user
                {
// printed out string[numargs+2] previously, and it says junk
                    int f = open(string[(numargs + 2)], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

                    if(f < 0)
                    {
                        printf("Unable to open output file\n");
                        status = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fflush(stdout);
                        dup2(f, STDOUT_FILENO);

                        close(f);

                    }
                }  

                j = execvp(string[0], args); // The first element of the string array is the first thing the user enters which is the command ls in this case
```

The file called junk gets created, but all that gets placed in it is junk. I have been struggling with this for a while so any help figuring out why the redirection won't work would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the research I did is correct then it is the part where I assign f to open the filename provided by the user, and dup2 standard output into the file.

Comment: I used print statements and they display up until the dup2(f, STDOUT_FILENO) command. I think this is where the error code is generating from.

Comment: Well, you can't print after that because you broke stdout. Print to stderr instead so that it will continue to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `execvp` to parse shell commands.

The redirection (>) character is understood by the shell (e.g., `bash`, `sh`, `ksh`) and `execvp` executes the command you pass it directly. It does not try and interpret the arguments and create file redirections, etc.

If you want to do that you need  to use the `system` call. See [System(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)

Similarly, any other special shell characters (pipe, *, ?, &, etc) won't work.

Comment: I parse the shell commands using strtok and they are inserted into an array. Thanks for the tip, I did change my for loop where I set up my args array so it only goes to the number of arguments instead of all the way through the string. This did not fix the problem however, I am still getting the same error code.

Comment: I see, but the error message tells us that the `ls` command is seeing > as an argument. Easier to use `system`.

Comment: I have to use exec functions because it is required in the assignment. I do not pass the redirection character to execvp, with the command "ls > junk" the only thing that would be passed to execvp is ls.

Comment: I will give you a big  tip. Computers don't lie. If it says "ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory" then that means you are passing the redirection character, even if you think you are not.

Comment: @Shaine Where is the code that you think removes the `>` from the arguments passed to `execvp`?

Comment: You were right rghome, I thought I had corrected the fact that > was in the arguments, but I was wrong. Once I fixed that it fixed the issue. Because of where my print statements stopped working I had it stuck in my head that the dup2 call was the problem. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
            j = execvp(string[0], args); // The first element of the string array is the first thing the user enters which is the command ls in this case
```

This will pass the `>` to `execvp`, which is obviously incorrect. You need to remove it from the arguments.